# mysql one to many in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables:

```
id_c    name    surname
 1      frank   pulio
 2      mark    adam
 3      peter   norton


id_v   id_c    data_visited    note
  1      1     2013-10-12      first visited to frank
  2      1     2013-10-16      second visited to frank
  3      2     2013-10-15      first visited to mark
  4      1     2013-10-20      third visited to frank
  5      2     2013-10-18      second visited to mark
```

I would get the customer name with the last data visited and note.

Example:

```
id_c   name   data_visited   note
  1    frank   2013-10-20    third visited to frank   
  2    mark    2013-10-18    second visited to mark
```

Comment: What about you show what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT t1.`id_c`,c.`name`,t1.latest,t1.`note` FROM `tablea`c

 INNER JOIN
 (
 SELECT t2.`id_c`,t2.latest,t3.`note` from `tableb` t3 

 INNER JOIN

 (SELECT `id_c`,MAX(`data_visited`) AS latest from
`tableb` 
GROUP BY(`id_c`))t2
 ON (t3.`id_c`=t2.`id_c`) AND (t3.`data_visited`=t2.latest)

)t1
ON(c.`id_c`=t1.`id_c`)
```

Comment: Wooo! I did not think it was so difficult...now work, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id_c, A.name, A.data_visited, A.note 
FROM (SELECT A.id_c, A.name, B.data_visited, B.note 
      FROM tableA A 
      INNER JOIN tableB B ON A.id_c = B.id_c 
      ORDER BY A.id_c, B.data_visited DESC) AS A 
GROUP BY A.id_c
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/164c2/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID_C |  NAME |                   DATA_VISITED |                   NOTE |
|------|-------|--------------------------------|------------------------|
|    1 | frank | October, 20 2013 00:00:00+0000 | third visited TO frank |
|    2 |  mark | October, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000 | SECOND visited TO mark |
```

Comment: this brings out everything. not just the last visit as the OP asked.

Comment: @mike Check the updated answer. No need to use sub query in sub query. You can directly get the result. Check the query and fiddle demo